# Align two UILabel texts

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont

I would like to align the start of the text of two `UILabel`s. I aligned the two `UILabel`s (with the yellow and grey background) and used `sizeToFit:` to shrink the `UILabel`s to the content but the text is not perfectly left aligned. There is a gap on the left. The gap is bigger or smaller depending on the first character. I would like to align the red lines in the following picture. There is even a small gap with the small font in the grey `UILabel` but it's barely visible.

[image]

With the `Z` character the gap is smaller but still visible by the yellow area left to the `Z`

[image]

A simple `UILabel` alignment does not help for my specific problem, because the text content is dynamic and not static. So there could be any combination depending on the data I get from the backend. Therefore I was hoping for a `UIFont` or `UILabel` attribute that could return the size of the gap based on the current rendering of the text.

I know that there are great `UIFont` related attributes like `baseline`, `capHeight` and `ascender` one can access to align text but there seems to be no attribute that would return the value of this gap on the left.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Any comments?

Comment: I removed `sizeToFit` in my code and used fixed label sizes just to eliminate the possible root problem of `sizeToFit`. I made the `UILabel` more wide to eliminate the right alignment assumption. It is still the same problem. It must be the Font rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Use attributed text of `UILabel`

set indentation as per your requirement 
ref screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn’t need to be two UILabels, you could have one with attributed text. Then both lines would be subject to the same layout.

Comment: Your solution sounded promising and I tried it. Unfortunately it renders exactly the same with one `UILabel` as with two `UILabel`s. I used a `\n` to add a line break to the `NSAttributedString` and added the `NSFontAttributeName` for the font styling. Same left gaps show up as with two separate `UILabel`s

Comment: Then this is probably some property of the font. You are probably going to have to get into individual glyphs and Core Text. Much lower level.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the GUI which people have been posting Screen Shots of, however... the behaviour is consistent with the very nature of typography.

The font sizes are completely different, therefore the width of an em is different, subsequently the letter-spacing is also different.

See this: http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm for more information.

I know this answer doesn't give you what you have asked for, however it should explain why this is happening.

For customisation such as this (if HTML and CSS) I would use a negative / positive margin on the sub text, however seeing as you are using backgrounds use padding (or the equivalent in your GUI).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think you are right that this behaviour is just the normal typography of a font. I used different fonts to see if the font I used was the source if the behaviour. But other fonts also generate this left gap.

Comment: I recently experienced this problem on the microsite I created for my Grid System: http://interiorsystem.co.uk - look at the very top, orange background area. The 2 lines of text demonstrate this. I had to use margin to line them up.

Comment: Looks nice. If you have fixed text and nothing dynamic this is definitely the simplest solution. In my case though, I have complete dynamic texts and a fixed margin does not solve it for all possible combinations.

Comment: Not saying it suits your situation, but it does demonstrate my point.

Comment: But then again, if it is dynamic as long as you understand your font sizes I don't see how it would fail. It would only be the content which changes, not the font size.

Comment: The gap on the left changes depending on the first character you have. Look at the images I added. The left gap for the `Z` is smaller compared to the left gap for `M` even if they have the same font size and style.

Comment: You can't change this on a per character basis. You'll have to find a 'happy medium' which will give you flexibility yet look good. Only a typographer will scrutinise this level of detail. Not your average user.

Comment: Another thing to consider here is the font family. Does it give you what you want? Maybe switch to a few different ones. They all behave differently. Some will have a Z that has a lower axis protruding, another won't.

Comment: I checked with a custom one and with the new San Francisco system font. Maybe the exact gaps are a little bit different but the main problem remains

Comment: If what you want is for an 'I' to line up with a 'Z' for example you may never get that level of precision with automation. You should set up a codepen with large font, small font, use a few fonts and lots of variations. If I get chance I'll do it.

Comment: Sorry to say it but what you want is not going to happen due to the nature of typography. This isn't anything to do with your GUI.

Answer (score -1):

Select both the labels and add a constraint called `align leading edges`.[image]